# PyQGIS reload a QGIS plugin

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-2, pyqt

I have a plugin that has a psycopg2 connection to a PostGIS database. When i close GUI with the X-Button and open it again, all the widgets are filled with the data from before. It looks like the X is only hiding the gui. 
Therefore I set the close event in the gui with

```
def closeEvent(self, event):
    qgis.utils.reloadPlugin('import_PostGis')
```

with the reloadPlugin methon I found in the QGIS utils file:

```
def reloadPlugin(packageName):
    """ unload and start again a plugin """
```

When the plugin is reseted it doesn't unload the Plugin from the tool bar but creates another icon from this plugin.

```
def initGui(self):
    """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

    icon_path = ':/plugins/import_PostGIS/icon.png'
    self.add_action(
        icon_path,
        text=self.tr(u'PostGis Import'),
        callback=self.run,
        parent=self.iface.mainWindow())

def unload(self):
    """Removes the plugin menu item and icon from QGIS GUI."""
    for action in self.actions:
        self.iface.removePluginMenu(
            self.tr(u'&PostGis Import'),
            action)
        self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)
```

So every time I close the plugin a new plugin is generated in the toolbar. Is something in my code wrong or is there another possibility to clear the widgtes of the plugin before starting it again?

Comment: Rather than reloading the whole plugin, why don't you write a function that resets the UI? You don't reboot your computer every time you want to close a program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a toolbar:

```
# Create toolbar
self.toolbar = self.iface.addToolBar("My Toolbar")
self.toolbar.setObjectName("My toolbar Plugin")
self.toolbar.addAction(self.action)
self.btn = QAction(QIcon(":/plugins/import_PostGIS/icon.png"), "button1",  self.iface.mainWindow())
QObject.connect(self.btn, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.method)
self.toolbar.addActions([self.btn])
```

and removing:

```
def unload(self):
    del self.toolbar
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. There is still another toolbar entry created when I close the plugin.

Comment: Don't loop through the actions, remove them individually.