# Dynamic menu actions from sqlite database QGIS using python

Tags: pyqgis, python-2.7

I want to have names for menu actions from sqlite database for QGIS Plugin dynamically.

```
       try:
            os.chdir(newPath)
            con = sqlite3.connect("db.sqlite")

            cur=con.cursor()
            cur.execute("""select queryLabel from custom_query;""") 
            cursor=cur.fetchall()
            for row in cursor:
                self.menu = QMenu( row[0], iface1.mainWindow().menuBar() )
                self.menu.setObjectName( row[0] )
                self.actionAttribute_Data=self.menu_WB_Query.addAction(row[0])
                #self.actionAttribute_Data.triggered.connect(self.attribute_data) 
        except sqlite3.Error, e:
            if con:
                con.rollback()
                print "Error %s:" % e.args[0]
                #sys.exit(1)
        finally:
            if con:
                con.close()
```

Putting this in `initgui()` I achieved the desired output, but as `initgui()` is called only once, the menu actions don't get refreshed if db is edited during execution of plugin.

Comment: Good and clear question. Have you tried qgis.utils.reloadPlugin('myplugin'). Take a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119418/pyqgis-reload-a-qgis-plguin. Hope you editing the db from within the plugin, since I see now way of popping an event from db to plugin.